# How does this self join work?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join, correlated-subquery

This is a problem from sqlzoo.net

Here is the table world:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|    name     | continent |  area   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      | 652230  |
| Albania     | Europe    | 2831741 |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 28748   |
| ...         | ...       | ...     |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

The Question:

Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:

The answer I am trying to understand is:

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL (SELECT area 
                   FROM world y
                   WHERE y.continent=x.continent
                   AND area>0)
```

This code gives:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+
| continent   |   name    |  area  |
+-------------+-----------+--------+
|Africa       | Algeria   | 2381741|
|Oceania      | Australia | 7692024|
|South America| Brazil    | 8515767|
|North America| Canada    | 9984670|
|Asia         | China     | 9596961|
|Caribbean    | Cuba      |  109884|
|Europe       | France    |  640679|
|Eurasia      | Russia    |17125242|
+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

I do not understand how this works. I think that the inner select should yield a table that contains all the areas and the outer select only chooses the biggest (`>=`). But how does it filter down to a list that seems to have been group by continent? How does `y.continent=x.continent AND area>0` work?

Comment: There are no JOINs in your query.  You do have a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain, I'll assume a world table with only 5 countries as follows:

```
Algeria      2381741
Australia    7692024
South Africa 1221037
New Zealand   268021
/*And to make it a little interesting:*/
Algeria Twin 2381741
```

The sub-query is matched to each row of the base query, 1-at-a-time. This is what's known as a correlated sub-query. Although correlated sub-queries work well, they are generally considered dangerous because of their tendency to yield poor performance characteristics if the optimiser cannot figure out a more efficient, equivalent structure.

The following table illustrates a logical view on how the data will be evaluated. Note that the database's query engine *might* be able to internally transform the plan into something mathematically equivalent, but far more efficient.

```
+-------------+--------------+--------+
| continent   |   name       |  area  |
+-------------+--------------+--------+
|Africa       | Algeria      | 2381741| >= ALL( /*y.continent='Africa'*/
                                               2381741, /*Alegria*/
                                               1221037, /*South Africa*/
                                               2381741) /*Alegria Twin*/
|Oceania      | Australia    | 7692024| >= ALL( /*y.continent='Oceania'*/
                                               7692024, /*Australia*/
                                               268021)  /*New Zealand*/
|Africa       | South Africa | 1221037| >= ALL( /*y.continent='Africa'*/
                                               2381741, /*Alegria*/
                                               1221037, /*South Africa*/
                                               2381741) /*Alegria Twin*/
|Oceania      | New Zealand  |  268021| >= ALL( /*y.continent='Oceania'*/
                                               7692024, /*Australia*/
                                               268021)  /*New Zealand*/
|Africa       | Algeria Twin | 2381741| >= ALL( /*y.continent='Africa'*/
                                               2381741, /*Alegria*/
                                               1221037, /*South Africa*/
                                               2381741) /*Alegria Twin*/
+-------------+--------------+--------+
```

From the above, rows 1, 2 and 5 are `>=` all the sub-query areas. So these are kept, while the other rows are discarded.

Note that there are a few ways to write the sub-query that will produce the exact same results.

Being `>=` all areas on a continent is the same as being `=` the MAX area on the continent.

```
WHERE area = ( SELECT MAX(y.area)
               FROM   world y
               WHERE  y.continent=x.continent)
```

Another way to get the maximum is to get the first row when ordering by area DESC.

```
WHERE area = ( SELECT y.area
               FROM   world y
               WHERE  y.continent=x.continent
               ORDER BY y.area DESC LIMIT 1)
```

However, be careful of the following which seems equivalent, but isn't.

```
/* The problem here is that only 1 Algeria will happen to be 
   first in the sub-query. Meaning 1 row will be missing from 
   the final result set. */
WHERE name = ( SELECT y.name
               FROM   world y
               WHERE  y.continent=x.continent
               ORDER BY y.area DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Finally, I mentioned that correlated sub-queries may have performance concerns. So it's generally advisable to consider rewriting a correlated sub-query into one that joins directly to the sub-query in the FROM clause if you can. E.g.

```
SELECT  x.contient, x.name, x.area
FROM    world x
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(y.area) as max_area, y.continent
            FROM   world y
            GROUP BY y.continent
        ) z ON
            x.continent = z.continent
        AND x.area = z.max_area
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT THIS, name, area 
FROM world X
WHERE area >= ALL (SELECT area 
                   FROM world y
                   WHERE y.continent = X.THIS
                   AND area > 0)
```

Note the capitalised `X` and `THIS`, they are the items that tie together the sub-query with the query.

In terms of functional effect<sup>(a)</sup>, the sub-query only returns rows related to the current row being processed at the query level.

So think of it this way. While processing the continent `Africa`, the sub-query is basically:

```
SELECT area
FROM   world y
WHERE  y.continent = 'Africa'
  AND  area > 0
```

and, because you have `WHERE area >= ALL [[that_sub_query]]` in the outer query, it will only give you rows where the area is at least as large as the largest area for that continent.

Or, more succinctly, *equal* to the largest since, in a given group, no one item can be simultaneously smaller than another and larger or equal to them all.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> How it works under the covers may be *vastly* different but the effect is what we're concerned with here.